# How could I improve this closed/deleted question about colonization?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, deleted-questions

The automatically/by-roomba deleted question is:
[How/Why do mainland people end up in an empire's colony? Eg Spaniards in the Philippines?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/68871/how-why-do-mainland-people-end-up-in-an-empires-colony-eg-spaniards-in-the-phi)

I thought it was pretty good.

But moderator MCW♦ said in a comment below the deleted question:

> This is a deceptively interesting question. I suspect that studying migration from the metropole to the colony is meaningless unless the migration is broken down into demographic groups. Different groups will have different motivations, but how to select demographics for further study?

Question 1: How could I improve this closed/deleted question about colonization?

Btw, I think this might relate to

1. Israeli settlements in Palestine / West Bank (wait are there any in Gaza?)
2. Code Geass - like again how/why do they end up there?

Question 2: Any idea if this might be better received on politics SE?

Comment: Step 1 for improvement would be to address the issues raised in comments.